# SSRS export to excel and retain data format

Tags: reporting-services

Good day,

may i ask if there is a way to export SSRS reports to Excel and still retain the correct data type?
ex. Date field when exported to excel should still be a date field, same with decimal or integers.

maybe a SSRS event/function that is called only if a report is exported excel and inside is a code that will render the fields data type properly?

I hope someone can enlighten me with this,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select the data field that you want to be formatted, then open the Properties window (F4). There is a property labeled "Format" and here is where you want to adjust the format so it will be display formats correctly in your Excel exports.

Example:

1 - Put "d" in Formats property and datetime fields will be displayed (and exported) in this format: mm/dd/yyyy

2 - Put "MM-dd-yy hh:mm tt" in Formats property and datetime fields will be displayed (and exported) in this format: mm-dd-yy 12 hr with AM/PM

There are a lot more formatting ways but this is just to give you an idea.